# Modifying pandas dataframe by row names

Tags: python, pandas

First, I think the question title doesn't explain the question well. Please feel free to change the title or recommend a better one.

I'm reading a CSV file in format: 
[image]

```
"sample","module","status","tot.seq","seq.length","pct.gc","pct.dup"
"ERR435952_cleaned_1","Basic Statistics","PASS","15529112","62",47,41.66
"ERR435952_cleaned_1","Per base sequence quality","FAIL","15529112","62",47,41.66
"ERR435952_cleaned_1","Per tile sequence quality","FAIL","15529112","62",47,41.66
"ERR435952_cleaned_1","Per sequence quality scores","PASS","15529112","62",47,41.66
"ERR435952_cleaned_1","Per base sequence content","PASS","15529112","62",47,41.66
"ERR435952_cleaned_1","Per sequence GC content","PASS","15529112","62",47,41.66
"ERR435952_cleaned_1","Per base N content","PASS","15529112","62",47,41.66
"ERR435952_cleaned_1","Sequence Length Distribution","PASS","15529112","62",47,41.66
"ERR435952_cleaned_1","Sequence Duplication Levels","WARN","15529112","62",47,41.66
"ERR435952_cleaned_1","Overrepresented sequences","WARN","15529112","62",47,41.66
"ERR435952_cleaned_1","Adapter Content","PASS","15529112","62",47,41.66
"ERR435952_cleaned_1","Kmer Content","FAIL","15529112","62",47,41.66
"ERR435952_cleaned_2","Basic Statistics","PASS","15529112","62",48,42.44
"ERR435952_cleaned_2","Per base sequence quality","PASS","15529112","62",48,42.44
"ERR435952_cleaned_2","Per tile sequence quality","WARN","15529112","62",48,42.44
"ERR435952_cleaned_2","Per sequence quality scores","PASS","15529112","62",48,42.44
"ERR435952_cleaned_2","Per base sequence content","PASS","15529112","62",48,42.44
"ERR435952_cleaned_2","Per sequence GC content","WARN","15529112","62",48,42.44
"ERR435952_cleaned_2","Per base N content","PASS","15529112","62",48,42.44
"ERR435952_cleaned_2","Sequence Length Distribution","PASS","15529112","62",48,42.44
"ERR435952_cleaned_2","Sequence Duplication Levels","WARN","15529112","62",48,42.44
"ERR435952_cleaned_2","Overrepresented sequences","WARN","15529112","62",48,42.44
"ERR435952_cleaned_2","Adapter Content","PASS","15529112","62",48,42.44
"ERR435952_cleaned_2","Kmer Content","FAIL","15529112","62",48,42.44
```

And I want to convert it to something like this, so I can create a simple heatmap based on PASS/FAIL/WARN values(including total number of reads : tot.seq):
[image]

I know I can do it by counting the number of rows(there is a correlation between interval for each module/feature value), but this is not exactly neat and I'm not sure if it is even efficient for a large dataset. Is there a way to map value according to name, rather than following the interval (that is i, i+n...so on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), also add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for columns from index and [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for remove `module` - column name:

```
df = df.set_index(['sample', 'tot.seq', 'module'])['status'].unstack() \
       .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
                sample   tot.seq Adapter Content Basic Statistics  \
0  ERR435952_cleaned_1  15529112            PASS             PASS   
1  ERR435952_cleaned_2  15529112            PASS             PASS   

  Kmer Content Overrepresented sequences Per base N content  \
0         FAIL                      WARN               PASS   
1         FAIL                      WARN               PASS   

  Per base sequence content Per base sequence quality Per sequence GC content  \
0                      PASS                      FAIL                    PASS   
1                      PASS                      PASS                    WARN   

  Per sequence quality scores Per tile sequence quality  \
0                        PASS                      FAIL   
1                        PASS                      WARN   

  Sequence Duplication Levels Sequence Length Distribution  
0                        WARN                         PASS  
1                        WARN                         PASS
```

But if get:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

then have duplicates and need aggregate data:

```
print (df)
                sample                       module status   tot.seq  \
0  ERR435952_cleaned_1             Basic Statistics   PASS  15529112   
1  ERR435952_cleaned_1    Per base sequence quality   FAIL  15529112   
2  ERR435952_cleaned_1    Per base sequence quality   FAIL  15529112   
3  ERR435952_cleaned_1  Per sequence quality scores   PASS  15529112   

   seq.length  pct.gc  pct.dup  
0          62      47    41.66  
1          62      47    41.66  
2          62      47    41.66  
3          62      47    41.66  

df = df.pivot_table(index=['sample', 'tot.seq'], columns='module', values='status', aggfunc=', '.join) \
       .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
                sample   tot.seq Basic Statistics Per base sequence quality  \
0  ERR435952_cleaned_1  15529112             PASS                FAIL, FAIL   

  Per sequence quality scores  
0                        PASS
```

---

```
df = df.groupby(['sample', 'tot.seq', 'module'])['status'].apply(', '.join).unstack() \
       .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)

                sample   tot.seq Basic Statistics Per base sequence quality  \
0  ERR435952_cleaned_1  15529112             PASS                FAIL, FAIL   

  Per sequence quality scores  
0                        PASS
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add the number of reads (tot.seq) in my initial question, since it is a repeating value for each sample(repeating for each module), how can I add it only once ?